# Displaylink not detecting external monitors on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, displaylink

Anyone who has/is successfully using Display link with evdi for external monitor on his arch linux? I’ve been struggling to make it work. I was on lts kernel before and learnt evdi is working best with latest arch kernel 5.16, so i switched to latest kernel. Even then it fails to work. I do see external monitors with display link when i use dmesg. But i never get the external monitor activate. If it helps, I’m using Hp USB C docking station. I could share more info if needed. I have been following arch wiki for display link. I have tried mode setting and other trouble shooting tips/workarounds in wiki. None of it worked yet.

Hardware used: System76 Lemur Pro 10

Any help or guidance is appreciated.
#evdi #displaylink #arch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using displaylink-beta package fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

The most viable place to look and interact with is https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/displaylink